# How to Optimize AWS API Gateway Latency During Resource Policy Validation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have been working on a new project utilizing API Gateway with a RequestAuthorizer and have observed a relatively high latency from the RequestAuthorizer, approximately 900ms for each new instance.

```
{
    "requestId": "20c86cad-4c6d-ca7808767960",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "resourcePath": "/api/v1/automations/{automationId}/recipient",
    "status": "201",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "85",
    "authorizeResultStatus": "200",
    "authorizerServiceStatus": "200",
    "authorizerLatency": "938",
    "authorizerRequestId": "71bcb639-bc4b-c21bdaeefb1e",
    "integrationRequestId": "0f660dad-8d5a-53ba79da0f17",
    "integrationLatency": "60",
    "integrationServiceStatus": "200"
}
```

Upon reviewing the execution logs, it appears that the latency is mainly due to API Gateway verifying the resource access policy. We confirmed this by stripping all code from our lambda handler, leaving only a static response.

[image: execution logs]

Is it typical for AWS to take this long to validate resource policies during cold starts? Are there specific configurations that could be applied to address this issue?

Comment: Please clarify: Did you identify the cold-start time of the custom authorizer as the bottleneck or another part of the flow? What's your methodology?

Comment: Hey @Maurice I have added the execution logs image in question for better context. Basically, we want to have our server response time less than 1 second, and by checking execution logs, you can see the API gateway took approx. 900 ms just to verify the resource access policy, which is our bottleneck.

Comment: Can you check the duration metric of the authorizer lambda? It seems like the cold starts there are causing your bottleneck and not the validation of its response.

Comment: The average running time of authorizerLambda is around 20 ms. As I mentioned, we are sending a static response.

Comment: The average doesn't matter - what's the max? is it the cold-start time of the Lambda container that makes some responses take that long to get?

Comment: The maximum time is 100 ms.